# Migrate a Trigger from MS Sql TO MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

I would like to convert this MS sql trigger to MySql.My issues are:

1. NOT FOR REPLICATION :
2. update() function:

I don't have any idea how to add that same functionality in MySql.Following is the SQL Server Trigger code.please help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [trigger_name] 
 ON  [dbo].[table_name]
 for INSERT,UPDATE NOT FOR REPLICATION 
AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if update(column_name) 
Begin
    Declare @SNo as varchar(50)
    Select @SNo = SNo From inserted
    IF Exists(Select * From inserted)  
    Begin
        exec procedure_name @SNo
    End
End
END
```